# Chrome Extension failing to upload in Chrome Web Store developer dashboard

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, manifest.json

Long time listener, first time caller...

I apologize if this has been answered, but I haven't been able to find it.

I'm having a grand ole' time trying to work with Chrome's developer dashboard.  The lovely error messages are so vague that they give me just about no insight at all into the cause of the problem.

I just updated my extension 2 days ago - yes, I had a frustrating time of it, but it worked eventually.  Well I overlooked a bug, which I quickly fixed, and now I'm trying to upload the new file.  I followed the same procedure that worked before, which I found here: http://www.adambarth.com/experimental/crx/docs/packaging.html under "Uploading a previously packaged extension to the Chrome Web Store"

So my process is to: Pack the new extension files(including the manifest.json), add the .crx file to a folder, add the "key.pem" file to that same folder, compress said folder, and upload to the Chrome dashboard.

I'm aware that this process puts the manifest.json file in the packed .crx file and not in the root of the zipped folder that I'm trying to upload.  Again, the above process worked before, and I've been trying in vain to repeat it today with no success.

The ONLY change made to my manifest file is the increment of the "version" number, as required.

I'm repeatedly getting the following:

> An error occurred: Failed to process your item.
>
> No manifest found in package. Please make sure to put manifest.json at
>   the root directory of the zip package.

My manifest.json, for whom it may concern...

```
{
    "name": "AppName",
    "version": "0.0.4",
    "description": "App description - information was changed for stackoverflow post",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "48": "img/pictureFile.png"
          }
    },
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],

      "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["*://linksRemovedForBrevity*"],
      "js":      ["content.js", "other-content.js"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "storage",
      "tabs"
    ], 
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "styles.css",
        "img/icon48.png"
    ]
}
```

I should mention that I'm a noob and don't know much of what I'm doing.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Simply make a ZIP, no need for CRX.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something stupid.  But if the files don't need to be packed into a .crx, why the emphasis on it in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

@wOxxOm got it.  The extension doesn't need to be packed to be zipped and uploaded.